# How to fix a mysql column value once inserted

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working on a dynamic website builder application writing on PHP and looking for a solution to have some of my mysql column value fixed once I inserted value in them. Fixed means completely fixed, no can update or alter that column value later once a value is inserted in that column row.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks

BlackBird Obscurite

Comment: so you want to lock 1 column in an inserted row?

Comment: You have 2 possibilities: either revoke the update-rights from the user, or write a trigger, that throws an excepion on update (which allows you have read-only permissions only on specific columns)

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing an update-trigger, that throws an exception if the user tries to change the value of specific columns:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE UPDATE ON yourTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.amount <=> OLD.amount OR NEW.col2 <=> OLD.col2 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot update row: its read-only';
    END IF;
END;
```

If you want all columns to be read-only, the better (and more efficient) approach is to revoke the users rights for update-statements on that table:

```
REVOKE UPDATE ON schema.yourTable FROM 'user'@'localhost';
```

Comment: I got an error #1193 - Unknown system variable 'p_status'  when I try below
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE UPDATE ON table40
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.type <=> OLD.type THEN
        SET p_status=’Unable to update the column: forbidden’;
    END IF;
END;

Comment: @user3631236 I updated my answer, it should work now